# Need help creating a simple regex in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl, replace

I'm still useless when it comes to creating regex patterns.  This one has got to be really easy.

Given the string: `/home/users/cheeseconqueso/perl.pl`

I want to place the string `./` right in front of the very last `/` in the original string to produce: `/home/users/cheeseconqueso/./perl.pl`

Thanks in advance - I'm sure this simple example will help me for a lot of other stupid stuff that shouldn't be up here!

Comment: You can have an upvote for making me laugh with the last paragraph :-P

Comment: Do you need to do this with a regex? It'd be fairly easy to split that string on `/`, then build it back up with the extra `.` in there.

Comment: i thought regex would be simplest - i was and still am messing around with `substr` but haven't thought of `split` like canspice mentions

Comment: Any time you think regexes will be the simplest solution, you're wrong. :-)

Comment: i guess your right considering John O's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my solution based on what I was thinking of when I left the comment to your question:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = '/home/users/cheeseconqueso/perl.pl';
my @arr = split('/',$str);
my $newstr = join('/', @arr[0..(@arr-2)], '.', $arr[-1]);
```

**Edit:** If you're really keen on using a regex, this is the simplest one I've found:

```
$str =~ s|(.*/)(.*)|$1./$2|;
```

It takes advantage of the greediness of the initial `*` in the first group to take every character up to the last `/`, then matches everything else in the second group. It's a little easier to read with the `|` delimiters so you avoid leaning toothpick syndrome.

Comment: Hehe, you added that comment while I was adding the regex edit. :-) It's all good, you got to find many more ways to get what you wanted.

Comment: switched to this answer because regex is more efficient and secondary split method useful to extract both path and file name - thanks CanSpice

Answer (score 4):

```
my $variable = "/home/users/cheeseconqueso/perl.pl";

$variable =~ s/(.*\/)([^\/]+)$/$1\.\/$2/;
```

Comment: this throws error Scalar found where operator expected at ./fnew.pl line 18, near "s/(.*\/)([^/]+)$/$1"
Backslash found where operator expected at ./fnew.pl line 18, near "$1\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
Final $ should be \$ or $name at ./fnew.pl line 18, within string

Comment: No problem CheeseConQueso! Note that you could also use a different delimiter so that you don't have to escape the forward slashes: `$variable =~ s#(.*/)([^/]+)$#$1\./$2#;`

Comment: I should know better than to post something without checking it at the prompt. Oops. Thanks Bart, sorry CCQ.

Comment: You don't need to escape the period. `s#(/[^/]+)$#/.$1#` should suffice.

Comment: @JohnO - at least you can write this stuff without testing it... i still dont know where to start (minus SO) when it comes to regex

Comment: You put () around anything you want to capture (to reuse in the second part of the substitution). A dot matches anything (mostly). A star means 0 or more of the preceding character... so if there is sometimes a D and sometimes not, you'd do D* so that it matches even if there is no D. If you know there will always be one D, but sometimes several, D+ works... + matches 1 or more of the preceding character. .+ matches anything, from one character in size on up to infinity. Sometimes that matches too much, the ? deals with greediness. .*?D will match everything on up until it finds a D.

Answer (score 3):

this is using File::Basename not with regex, you can use this cpan module if you find hard to write regex.

```
use File::Basename;
$path = '/home/users/cheeseconqueso/perl.pl';
$newpath = dirname($path) . './'.basename($path);
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need a regex, you can just `split` the string:

```
my $str='/home/users/cheeseconqueso/perl.pl';

#Array: ('','home','users','cheeseconqueso','perl.pl')
my @arr=split(/\//,$str); 

my $output=join('/',@arr[0..($#arr-2)]); # '/home/users/cheeseconqueso'
$output.='/./' . $arr[$#arr]; #Pops on the '/./' and the last element of @arr.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s/(.*)\/(.*)/\1.\/\2/
```

As noted by CanSpice, split works fine here too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my $str = "/home/users/cheeseconqueso/perl.pl";
if($str =~ /^(.*)(\/)(\w+\.\w+)$/) {
    $str = $1.'/.'.$2.$3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex? We don't need no stinkin' regex.

l-value substr() to the rescue!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

$_ = "/home/users/cheeseconqueso/perl.pl\n";
substr($_, rindex($_, '/'), 0) = '/.';
print;
```

Comment: this is what i initially tried doing... not sure why they -1'd you because other people didnt answer regex either